# How to put the double quotes before array square brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, replace, quotes

consider I have array class:["A, "B","C","D"] and I want output "[A,B,C,D]" .

I am working with React and all these fields comes dynamically to my array, before doing post method I want the output as mentioned. kindly help me with this

Comment: `\`[${["A", "B", "C", "D"] .join()}]\``

Comment: I have a query regarding converting your array with surrounding double quotes, do you want to stringify your response if yes then you should use JSON stringify which @FLiotta suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(["A", "B","C","D"])` should do the work, you can learn more about the JSON object and its methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify)

Comment: I have done this but not getting hte result. it removes double quotes but doesnt add before square brackets

Comment: What about `'"' + JSON.stringify(["A", "B","C","D"]) + '"'` ? JSON.stringify returns a string, so you can just concat the "

Comment: @FLiotta solution is much more apt and accurate user13738899 you might be sending incorrect data in POST, could you check please

Comment: @FLiotta Thanks for you suggestion. That Worked

Answer (score 0):

```
`"[${["A", "B", "C", "D"].join(',')}]"`
```

Comment: The `','` in `join()` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String` object of js to convert the array data to string and  template to convert to your goal.

```
let data = ["A", "B","C","D"]
console.log(`[${String(data)}]`)
```

in this case `String(data) // ["A,B,C,D"]`